# Displaying Image from Azure Blob Storage container without revealing URL in .NET 6/7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an image in an Azure blob storage container that needs to be displayed. The image contains sensitive data and therefore the URL cannot be revealed. The storage account and the key vault containing the connection credentials are secured using Managed Identity. I am a Junior Dev and am looking for the best practice to implement this. I am using .NET6/Razor Pages for both front and back end. Thank you for any/all advice and help!

I have tried using the blob storage API to get the blobs in the container, and that works as intended. However the URL is revealed and the image can be downloaded.

Comment: You need to link to the store so an url is needed. You could hide that one in the client by using base64 encoded src instead of using the link so actually embedding the image in the html page like `<img src="data:image/png;base64, 0xXXXXXXXXX">` for example.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the image contains sensitive data"? A watermark? Or sensitive metadata? In either case, if the client gets the image, he'll be able to save it locally and extract that data.

Comment: The image itself is sensitive data that should only be able to be viewed and nothing else. Sorry for not being more clear! So all I have to do is encode it and pass that as the source? I have been way overthinking this!

Comment: As already mentioned, you can't prevent someone from downloading a typical image. You could try using a Digital Rights Management system to prevent it, but if someone wants the image they could open the browser in a VM and take a screenshot even if its DRM protected.

Comment: That's an impossible to solve requirement then. If the client has the image its his and he can do everything with it its out of your hand. You can't really enforce "view only".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in the comments: That's not something you can solve by technical means. Everybody that can view the image can also store it (or take a screenshot - in the ugliest case with a cell phone). This problem needs to be solved by trust. If you hrust the person viewing the image, you need to trust him that he's not abusing the image (or any data he's working with, by the way). If you don't trust him, don't give him access.

This kind of problems really cannot be solved by technical means, only by the "human factor".